# JSF dynamic include using Ajax request

Tags: ajax, dynamic, include, jsf-2, primefaces

In JSF2, is it possible to change the of value of src of ui:include dynamically using Ajax request (like for example PrimeFaces p:commandButton)?
Thank you.

```
<h:form>                        
    <h:commandLink value="Display 2" action="#{fTRNav.doNav()}">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{fTRNav.pageName}" value="/disp2.xhtml" />
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>

<ui:include src="#{fTRNav.pageName}"></ui:include>
```

That's what I have right now. Is it possible to make it Ajax (using p:commandButton)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The JSTL tags as proposed in the other answer are not necessary and it is not nicely reuseable.

Here's a basic example using pure JSF (assuming that you runs Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2, otherwise you indeed need to use `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` like as in your question):

```
<h:form>
    <f:ajax render=":include">
        <h:commandLink value="page1" action="#{bean.setPage('page1')}" />
        <h:commandLink value="page2" action="#{bean.setPage('page2')}" />
        <h:commandLink value="page3" action="#{bean.setPage('page3')}" />
    </f:ajax>
</h:form>

<h:panelGroup id="include">
    <ui:include src="#{bean.page}.xhtml" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

with

```
private String page;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.page = "page1"; // Ensure that default is been set.
}

// Getter + setter.
```

Comment: Yes I am using servlet 3.0, but I am not quite sure about the version of EL (how can I know it?). I was about to ask this question, because I definitely didn't want to use JSTL. And this one looks better. Thank you.

Comment: EL 2.2 comes hand in hand with Servlet 3.0. So as long as your web.xml is declared conform Servlet 3.0 (and you don't have any proprietary `el-api.jar`, `el-impl.jar` etc in your `/WEB-INF/lib`), it'll work.

Answer (score 3):

here is how I render subcontent dynamically using MnagedBean. First I set page in the center (that will be changed by menu triggers) with `private String name="/main_pages/mainpage.xhtml"`, then each time submenu is clicked the HelloBean resets `"name"` and contents is updated by `update=":content"` - then new name is retrieved from Bean:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">




        <h:head>
            <f:facet name="first">
                <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>

            </f:facet>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>

            <p:layout fullPage="true">

                <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="150" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                    <h1>Madeline<br>shop</br></h1>
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                    Zapraszamy do odwiedzania naszego biura!
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="175" header="Menu" collapsible="true">
                    <h:form>
                    <p:menu>
                            <f:ajax render=":content">
                            <p:menuitem value="O naszej agencji" action="#{helloBean.setName('/main_pages/onas.xhtml')}" update=":content" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Ubezpieczenia pojazdów" action="#{helloBean.setName('/main_pages/ubpoj.xhtml')}" update=":content" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Ubezpieczenia majątkowe" action="#{helloBean.setName('/main_pages/ubmaj.xhtml')}" update=":content" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Ubezpieczenia na życie" action="#{helloBean.setName('/main_pages/ubnaz.xhtml')}" update=":content" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Zapytaj" action="#{helloBean.setName('/main_pages/zapytaj.xhtml')}" update=":content" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Kontakt" action="#{helloBean.setName('/main_pages/kontakt.xhtml')}" update=":content" />
                            </f:ajax>
                    </p:menu>
                    </h:form>
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="center">

                    <br></br><br></br>
                    <p:panel id="content">
                                        <ui:include src="#{helloBean.name}" />
                    </p:panel>       

                </p:layoutUnit>

            </p:layout>

        </h:body>



</html>
```

my ManagedBean:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;
/**
 *
 * @author root
 */
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of HelloBean
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name="/main_pages/mainpage.xhtml";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `<c:if test="condition">` tag around the ui:include and then when the ajax button is clicked, the panel that holds the ui:include is refreshed.

**Example**:

First make sure that the jstl core taglib is included by inserting the following namespace in the document:

`<html xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core>"`

Then, you can use the `<c:if>` tag as follows :

```
<c:if test="#{!logBean.loggedIn}">
    <ui:include src="loginpage.xhtml" />
</c:if>
<c:if test="#{logBean.loggedIn}">
    <ui:include src="home.xhtml" />
</c:if>
```

Comment: Does that work with ajax request?